# X-editable $(...).editable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, x-editable

I have

```
 <tr>
     <td><i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Site</td>
     <td>
         <a href="{{$url}}" id="username" data-type="string" data-pk="1" data-name="username" data-url="post.php" data-toggle="#pencil" data-default="'click'">{{$url}}</a>
         <a href="#" id="pencil" style="float: right"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
     </td>
</tr>
```

and

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>

<script>

   $(function(){
   $('#pencil').click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       $('#username').editable('toggle');
       $('#pencil').hide();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.editable-cancel, .editable-submit', function(){
       $('#pencil').show();
    });
 });
</script>
```

As a result: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).editable is not a function
 (`$('#username').editable('toggle');` - here)

but when i had just `$('#username').editable();` everything works fine, by default, but on this element. When I need it to work when I click on a button (#pencil).

Can someone help me? I've already spent a lot of time on this. And I really do not see what's wrong.

Comment: That doesn't look to be possible, are you sure that `boostrap-editable.js` is being loaded?

Comment: Yes, it's loading

Comment: And I now tried to change `<script src="/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>`on `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>`. Same error.

Comment: Are you allowed to pass a string in? Also, are you running a local server or accessing the file directly? Please make sure the javascript is loading as `.editable is not a function` means that it's unlikely it is.

Comment: At the expense of the string, now it's not so important (But the default manual table is true). I start everything on the local server. And yes `.editable` is loaded as JS function. The fact that before that she worked. (As I wrote before, it worked, but when I started building a structure with toggl, it stopped)

Comment: Try to change data-type="string" to data-type="text"

Answer (score 1):

For someone who's getting this error on asp.net mvc partial view, I resolved this by adding the reference only in the main view.

I had added jquery and xeditable references in all partial views, which were conflicting which each other.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error,
but later on i realized that there seems to be an bug in this version of boostrap.editable.js(cdn) ,

as you are on a cdn network, so its not possible to made changes there.

all you can do is to use a different stable version of cdn who have this function defined.

simply put this cdn just after yours and it will initilize
.editable function for your window context.

```
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

**Hope it works** .